# Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint, but there aren't any duplicates

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm trying to load data into SQL using LINQ. When I get to `context.SubmitChanges()`, the following exception is thrown:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.Linq.dll

Additional information: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__SDA_Cont__403B95D755FFB06A'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.SDA_Contracts'. The duplicate key value is (3M).
```

Here is the code which produces the error. I've manually gone into the data (by tacking on an order by and viewing it in the debugger). There are no duplicate entries as the exception would suggest.

```
var noDuplicates = query
    .GroupBy(x => x.ContractingParty)
    .Select(x => x.First());
var duplicates = query
    .Select(x => { x.ContractingParty = x.ContractingParty + "-2"; return x; })
    .GroupBy(x => x.ContractingParty)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .Select(x => x.Skip(1).Take(1).Single());
Console.WriteLine(query.Count() + " Total entries");
Console.WriteLine(noDuplicates.Count() + " Unique entries based on contracting party");
Console.WriteLine(duplicates.Count() + " Non-unique entries");

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (DataContext context = new DataContext(conn))
    {
        Table<Contract> contracts = context.GetTable<Contract>();
        Table<Attachment> attachments = context.GetTable<Attachment>();
        contracts.InsertAllOnSubmit(noDuplicates);
        contracts.InsertAllOnSubmit(duplicates);
        context.SubmitChanges();
        Console.WriteLine("Contracts inserted");
     ....
```

I've tried commenting `contracts.InsertAllOnSubmit(duplicates);` to be certain there are no duplicate entries, and the exception is still thrown. The enraging part about this is the program worked a few days ago. The database schema is the same, the program hasn't changed, but for some reason the program no longer runs.

I've ensured there aren't any null values in the Contract objects. The Contract class is defined as:

```
[Table(Name = "SDA_Contracts")]
class Contract : IEquatable<Contract>
{
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, Name = "contractId")]
    public int ContractId;

    [Column(Name = "contractingParty")]
    public string ContractingParty;
....
```

Comment: To track the issue please insert one by one entry in Database.

Comment: What's already in the table? Even if the data you're adding has no duplicates, the data in the table may already contain them. Also, are you sure that adding "-2" will guarantee a new unique key?

Comment: The `noDuplicates` test does not guarantee that you are not attempting to insert duplicate entries - for example, the collation in the database for that column may be case insensitive, but your `GroupBy` on a string, would, by default, be case sensitive. So you could have two values, "3m" and "3M" that you would attempt to insert.

Comment: I've attempted adding a foreach to make the insertions 1 entry at a time. It throws the exception after attempting to submit the change after the very first insertion.

Comment: @siride Yes, there are never more than 2 entries for the same contract.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I was connecting to the wrong database. I'll show myself out.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot to set `WHERE` in query.